# Order by ID ASC not working in WordPress Query

Tags: wordpress

I have tried but not working only showing DESC order  , what is wrong here please help

```
if( $terms ) :
        foreach( $terms as $term ) :
         $arg = array(
          'post_type' => 'post', 
          'posts_per_page' =>-1, 
          'post_status' => 'publish', 
          'tax_query' =>array(
                array(
              'taxonomy' => 'category',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => array($term->name)
           )
          ),
        'orderby'   => 'ID',
        'order' => 'ASC'
        );

         $tthe_query = new WP_Query( $arg );
```

Comment: In this use meta key.

Comment: if( $terms ) :
            foreach( $terms as $term ) :
             $arg = array(
              'post_type' => 'post', 
              'posts_per_page' =>-1, 
              'post_status' => 'publish', 
              'tax_query' =>array(
                 array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'category',
                  'field' => 'slug',
                  'terms' => array($term->name)
               )
              ),
   'meta_key'       => 'number',
      'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
      'order'          => 'ASC'
            ); still not working